# Time complexity of nested for loop?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

This question is for revision from a past test paper just wondering if i am doing it right.

im new to this, so im having a bit of difficulty with more complicated questions. this is one of them...

If anyone could elaborate on this, i'll be very grateful...
So i have to find out the complexity of this piece of code...

```
cout = 0;
for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i*=3)
   for(int j=1 ; j<=i; j++)
      for(int k=1 ; k<=n ; k++)
          count++;
```

so, i tried doing it...and i got O(n^2logn)..
its not correct...the answer should be O(n^2)..
can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: I would have thought it would be O(n^3). When i=0, then the complexity is O(n^2), but then when i=n, the complexity is O(n^3).

Comment: I guess k should be initted to 0.

Comment: `i` is not equal to `0` or `n` in the sense used above; it is the loop variable, after all.

Comment: yeah..made a mistake...correcting it :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The number of iterations of the second loop is
$$  1 + 3 + 9 + ... + m  $$
where  $m$  is roughly $n$. This sums to $\Theta(n)$.  Then the innermost loop is another factor of Theta(n). So $\Theta(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

A formal manner to determine the time complexity of your algorithm:

[image]